# Can a method from a Generic class return a Tuple with the same types as its argument-list?

Tags: ceylon

I wanted to have something like this:

```
[String, Integer] values = SomeClass("Hi", 1).values();
[Boolean, Float] others = SomeClass(true, 2.0).values();

// EDIT - should return tuple with same type as the arguments list
[String] strs = SomeClass("Strings").values();
```

Is this possible with Ceylon generics?

I suspect something similar to this should be possible after reading [about currying in Ceylon](http://ceylon-lang.org/blog/2013/01/21/abstracting-over-functions/), but I can't figure this out right now!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
class SomeClass<Args>(Args args)
            given Args satisfies Tuple<Anything, Anything, Anything[]> {
    shared Args values() => args;
}

[String, Integer] foo = SomeClass(["Hi", 1]).values();
[Boolean, Float] bar = SomeClass([true, 2.0]).values();
[String] baz = SomeClass(["Strings"]).values();
```

Comment: I was actually asking about having any number of arguments.... sorry I did not make that clear... both my examples had 2 arguments, but I needed this to be able to handle any number of arguments...

Comment: @Renato, see my edit. Tell me if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: This is awesome, thanks! It will actually be really useful to my project.

Comment: @Renato, this answer is much better now.